justAudio used very simply per the example creates an Exception
I have completed an app using Just Audio. I built it following the example provided. I want to add background music. I thought I followed Ryan Heise's example for a simple player. I must be missing something. I receive the following Exception:
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'MediaItem' in type cast)
on this line:
await musicPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(url)));
Here is the function that fails with this line:
Future<void> playBackgroundMusic() async {
    int rng = Random().nextInt(7);
    // Inform the operating system of our app's audio attributes etc.
    // We pick a reasonable default for an app that plays speech.
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
    String musicFilename = filenameList[rng];
    String url =
        "MY_SERVER/music/$musicFilename";
    final musicPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    try {
          await musicPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(url)));
    } on PlayerException catch (e) {
      print("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
    musicPlayer.play();
  }


This function is called by the first initState in the app:
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    playBackgroundMusic();
  }

A similar question 78571039 was asked and the answer given was to import Audio Service and add this code:
AudioSource.uri( Uri.parse(item.music), tag: MediaItem( id: "${item.id}", album: "${musicImage}", title: "${item.name}", artUri: Uri.parse('${musicImage}'), ), ),

This solved my problem - but there is no way I would have known this from the Just Audio documentation. I think this indicates that something (documentation) or code needs to change in Just Audio. This problem was not solved on Github in September 2023 due to lack of specificity. https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/991.
So I am asking either to be pointed to the existing documentation that says this import and line of code is required or to update the documentation. This is too good of a plugin to have something that would keep people from using it.

why you are posting it here: plugin should.., good of a plugin to have..??
Is it possible to better write your thoughts and respects on the GitHub plugin?

The author of the plugin asked that we respond on Stackoverflow and closed the issue on Github without answering it.
